# How can I auto increment numbered results with the DOM in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns results , How do I approach auto increment  so I can number my results? Do I need to use a loop?

```
function addEventOutputTracking(outputText, extraText) {
  var num = 1;
  var node;//for element to add child element later
  var pChildNode = document.createElement("p");//new element that will be child of node

  //new document parts created, so add them to document
  node = document.getElementById("eventOutput"); //existing div we are adding to
  node.appendChild(pChildNode); //adding p element as child of div
  pChildNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(num + 1 + outputText + " " + extraText)); //adding text to new p element

}//end function addEventOutputTracking
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `className` to `p` element, use `.length` of elements having `className` returned by `document.querySelectorAll(/* className */)` to increment

```
var pChildNode = document.createElement("p");
pChildNode.className = "abc";
node.appendChild(pChildNode);
pChildNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
  document.querySelectorAll(".abc").length + outputText + " " + extraText)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var addEventOutputTracker=(function(){
    var num=1;
    return function(outputText,extraText) {
          var node;//for element to add child element later
          var pChildNode = document.createElement("p");//new element that will be child of node
//new document parts created, so add them to document
          node = document.getElementById("eventOutput"); //existing div we are adding to
          node.appendChild(pChildNode); //adding p element as child of div
          pChildNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode((num++) + outputText + " " + extraText)); //adding text to new p element
    }
})();
```

Comment: Would `num++` be `2` at each call to `addEventOutputTracker` ?

Comment: No. num will increments at each call to addEventOutputTracker. The explain "Why num is increments?" I recommend to read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: _"No. num will increments at each call to addEventOutputTracker."_ Does `var num=1` set `num` to `1` at each call to `addEventOutputTracker` ?

Comment: No. `var num=1` is a part of anonymous function. This function returns the body of addEventOutputTracker. So, num is sealed in closure. Please, read the article from the my previous comment.